# how to change background color of amchart gauge graph in angular 6

Tags: angular6, amcharts

I am using gauge graph of amchart having multiple axes with the help of following code from amchart tutorial in my angular6 app.

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "theme": "red",
  "type": "gauge",
  "backgroundColor":"#67b7dc",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisColor": "#67b7dc",
    "axisThickness": 3,
    "endValue": 240,
    "gridInside": false,
    "inside": false,
    "radius": "100%",
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "tickColor": "#67b7dc",
    "backgroundColor":"#67b7dc"
  }, {
    "axisColor": "#fdd400",
    "axisThickness": 3,
    "endValue": 160,
    "radius": "40%",
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "tickColor": "#fdd400"
  } ],
  "arrows": [ {
    "color": "#67b7dc",
    "innerRadius": "20%",
    "nailRadius": 0,
    "radius": "85%"
  } ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

The code works fine in my angular app, but I failed to add backgroundcolor to the axes.I found there is an option for chaging the border color of the axes, but how can I add different background colors for the two axes?

Comment: Gauge Axes don't have a backgroundColor property. Are you referring to the color of the bands in the unfilled portion of your gauge like in [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/solid-gauge/) and [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-gauge/)?

Comment: ok.when i adding color to a band with or without specifying the gradient ratio it will always be a lighter color.how can i add the color to a band withou having lightening effect?

Comment: Set [`bandAlpha`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GaugeAxis#bandAlpha) to 1 in each of your axes that have the bands. Your custom theme is likely setting it to a different value than the default.

Comment: thanks brother....

Comment: i have one more doubt in the am chart tutorial, they said that when gradient ratio is positive then band color will be lighter.but when i  increase the values there is no change in the band color lightening.how can i make the band color more transparent

Comment: `bandAlpha` controls the band's transparency, but using positive values in `gradientRatio` do lighten the color as expected. Post a fiddle.